# How would you access a specific index in a My.Settings ArrayList using String Format

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, my.settings

i've an ArrayList Saved in My.Settings
i am trying to Access it using some string, Here is the code so you get what i am trying to do

```
If listBoxEdit1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        My.Settings("Sup" & listBoxEdit1.SelectedIndex + 1 & "(1)") = Convert.ToDouble(Margin2TextBox.Text)
    End If
```

i need to specify the value for My.Settings.Sup1(1)

How would you do it?

i've Multiple ArrayLists which goes form  My.Settings.Sup1 to My.Settings.Sup20
so the `listBoxEdit1.SelectedIndex+1` specifies the number of the ArrayList but i can't figure out how to get the index

also tried

```
My.Settings("Sup" & listBoxEdit1.SelectedIndex + 1 &"("& 1 & ")")
```

also

```
My.Settings("Sup" & listBoxEdit1.SelectedIndex + 1).Item(1)
```

Comment: so i guess its not possiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select `StringCollection` as Type of your setting.

[image]

Then you can easily access a specific element with an index.

```
Dim setting As StringCollection = My.Settings.MySetting
Dim value1 = My.Settings.MySetting(1)
Dim value2 = My.Settings.MySetting(2)
Dim valueX = My.Settings.MySetting.Item(X)
```

---

**Edit**

If your setting is called `Sup1`, you can access it via `My.Settings("Sup1")` or My.Settings("Sup" & whatever). Then, you have your `ArrayList` or `StringCollection` and can access its items like every other `ArrayList` or `StringCollection`.

So your code should probably read:

```
 My.Settings("Sup" & listBoxEdit1.SelectedIndex + 1)(1) = Convert.ToDouble(Margin2TextBox.Text)
```

Here's another example:

```
My.Settings.MySetting1 = New StringCollection()

My.Settings("MySetting" & 1).Add("FooBar")
My.Settings("MySetting" & 1).Add("123456")

My.Settings("MySetting" & 1)(0) = "Hey, what's up?"

MsgBox(My.Settings("MySetting" & 1)(1))
```

Comment: but it makes not difference..i can access the index in my ListView as My.Settings.Sup1(1) , but the prolblem is as i described above